# Python multiprocessing an enourmous amount of data

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have searched the site but I am not sure precisely what terms would yield relevant answers, my apologies if this question is redundant.

I need to process a very very large matrix (14,000,000 * 250,000) and would like to exploit Python's multiprocessing module to speed things up. For each pair of columns in the matrix I need to apply a function which will then store the results in a proprietary class.

I will be implementing a double four loop which provides the necessary combinations of columns.

I do not want to load up a pool with 250,000 tasks as I fear the memory usage will be significant.Ideally, I would like to have one column then be tasked out amongst the pool I.e 
Process 1 takes Column A and Column B and  a function F takes A,B and G and then stores the result in Class G[A,B]
Process 2 takes Column A and Column C and proceeds similarly

The processes will never access the same element of G.

So I would like to pause the for loop every N tasks. The set/get methods of G will be overriden to perform some back end tasks.

What I do not understand is whether or not pausing the loop is necessary? I.e is Python smart enough to only take what it can work on? Or will it be populating a massive amount of tasks?

Lastly, I am unclear of how the results work. I just want them to be set in G and not return anything. I do not want to have to worry about about `.get()` etc. but from my understanding the pool method returns a result object. Can I just ignore this?

Is there a better way? Am I completly lost?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: There's nothing to show at this point. I'm just trying to figure out how the MP module works.

Comment: python is not the best choice if you want to manually process (using loops) large amounts of data. Even if you use `multiprocessing`, the interpreter overhead is too high. If you're doing numerical calculations, you might want to give numpy a try

Comment: Thank you for your response. Numpy will be taking care of some things on the backend (i.e the columns will be np.matrix). The problem is I need a very specific implementation of matrix functions given memory constraints and the structure of the matrix.

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is the [producer-consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) pattern, when you mention "pausing" your for-loop.

Comment: As for the second part of your question, you cannot share arbitrary objects between processes. That means you cannot change G from your worker processes directly. You will need to look at the results returned from your pool workers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off - you will want to create a multiprocessing pool class. You setup how many workers you want and then use map to start up tasks. I am sure you already know but here is the python [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) docs.

You say that you don't want to return data because you don't need to but how are you planning on viewing results? Will each task write the data to disk? To pass data between your processes you will want to use something like the [multiprocessing queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes).

Here is example code from the link on how to use process and queue:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def f(q):
    q.put([42, None, 'hello'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    print q.get()    # prints "[42, None, 'hello']"
    p.join()
```

And this is an example of using the Pool:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)              # start 4 worker processes
    result = pool.apply_async(f, [10])    # evaluate "f(10)" asynchronously
    print result.get(timeout=1)           # prints "100" unless your computer is *very* slow
    print pool.map(f, range(10))          # prints "[0, 1, 4,..., 81]"
```

Edit: @goncalopp makes a very important point that you may not want to do heavy numerical calculations in python due to how slow it is. [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) is a great package for doing number crunching.

If you are heavily IO bound due to writing to disk on each process you should consider running something like 4*num_processors so that you always have something to do. You also should make sure you have a very fast disk :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. My concern is that I do not want to inflate the pool; will python only take the tasks it can handle in a given instance? Or will it load everything into the pool and proceed to work? The results are stored elsewhere, I have no intention of viewing them, only performing more operationson them.

Comment: The pool is limited to the number of workers you give it. It will not start a new task until the current work is done. This means that each task can 1. Apply the function to the data 2. store in G  then finally that process will end and a new one will start with the next chunk of data.

Comment: I think there is a disconnect between what you think is going into the queue and what we think. To meter your memory usage, you should load your column groups onto the queue as needed (i.e to maintain a length of 10). Then your workers (say one for each processor) will pull items from the queue and process them. What we still don't understand is what you want to do with the new modified structures as you make them. ("write data to disk?").

Comment: Thanks Ben. That helps. If I use apply_async do I need to .get() in order for the process to proceed to the next task? I noted that it takes a call back function, if this just returns nothing, is that sufficient for my purposes?

Comment: He says that "The set/get methods of G will be overriden to perform some back end tasks." Which means that the data will probably be saved there in a db or disk. I assume that his main process will be loading matrix data and have the tasks pulling, processing, and dumping memory.

Comment: @BenEchols wouldn't his bottleneck be writing to memory then? Thats actually an instance where python threading can be useful (IO bound)

Comment: @ Paul I do indeed intend on writing them to disk.

Comment: @MichaelChase you would probably want to use the pool.map() function. I am not sure how you will be getting the data to the processes but I would recommend using the queue class I linked and then after starting the child processes using the main process to load data into the queue. You can watch for the size of the queue and load data as the child processes grab items.

Comment: If each of the pool processes are writing to disk you are going to be pretty heavily IO bound. I still wouldn't recommend using the threading classes. In my own performance testing even IO bound tasks will run much better using multiprocessing than threading as most modern computers have multiple cores which lets the OS schedule across processors.

Comment: @MichaelChase Unless this is running on a pretty snazzy machine, you should start putting the completed items into queues to be written to memory by a threaded or multiprocessed python process. I have used threading in my experience but Ben seems to have had better luck with multiprocessing. Conveniently, it sounds like you want to pause processing anyway so that should give your writer threads time to catch up between processing.

Comment: @Ben the backend will be managing the IO and only writing as needed so it ought not be that bad as the work can proceed sequentially. You've answered my questions, thank so much!

Comment: Note that by default a `Pool` will not start a larger number of worker than there are cores in the machine. Too many worker processes will only lead them to fight over resources instead of doing useful work. Therefore I would suggest you start with the default number and do some throughput test while gradually increasing the number to 2x #cores. See where the performance tops out.